# Slide/Fade jQuery Slider

Tags: jquery, slider, fade

I'm looking to build my own very simple slider with jQuery and want it to include two features:

- The sliding effect
- The fadeout/fadein image effect.

I haven't been able to figure out a way to mix both, and especially to keep things simple.

Any ideas? I'm looking for how the HTML structure should be and how the JavaScript code will change it.

Comment: explain what's a slider. my concept of slider is this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Comment: You will have to use the animate function. I will try and throw something together quick on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/rvJeh/2/
Here is what it would look like sliding left 50 and fading to 0 over 1500 ms.

Answer (score 1):

http://slidefade.lulibi.com

Would this work for you?